# Special Characters in JS, how to use "/" character

Tags: javascript, character, vbulletin

I've vbulletin 4.2.0 i added an special button to it's editor with this article;

http://www.vbulletinguru.com/2012/add-a-new-toolbar-button-to-ckeditor-tutorial/

The thing i want to do is add an syntax highlighter code with this button.

When i use below code it's working fine;

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'YourPluginName',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand( 'SayHello',
            {
                exec : function( editor )
                {    
                        editor.insertHtml( "Hello from my plugin" );
                }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'YourPluginName',
        {
            label: 'My Button Tooltip',
            command: 'SayHello',
            icon: this.path + 'YourPluginImage.png'
        } );
    }
} );
```

so i changed this code to this, because i wannt to add specific text like below;

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'DKODU',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand( 'SayHello',
            {
                exec : function( editor )
                {
                        editor.insertHtml( '[kod=delphi][/kod]' );
                }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'DKODU',
        {
            label: 'My Button Tooltip',
            command: 'SayHello',
            icon: this.path + 'star.png'
        } );
    }
} );
```

after update the code when i press the button nothings happen, i checked with google and this site but i couldn't figure it out i think i made mistake with some special characters but i couldn't find what's the problem.

If i made some mistakes when i publish this question forgive me and also forgive me for my bad english, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for everybody's answers, i solved with this

```
var baslangic="[kod=delphi]";
var bitis="[/kod]";
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'DKODU',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand( 'DKODU',
            {
                exec : function( editor )
                {    
                 editor.insertHtml(baslangic);
                 editor.insertHtml('');
                 editor.insertHtml(bitis);
                }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'DKODU',
        {
            label: 'Delphi Kodu Ekle',
            command: 'DKODU',
            icon: this.path + 'star.png'
        } );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the '/' using a '\' just like we do in C/C++ or all those other languages

so,

```
editor.insertHtml( '[kod=delphi][\/kod]' );
```

Comment: If I remember right, `/` doesn't need to be escaped ([this](http://i.imgur.com/c6InN.png) works in chrome, and I'm sure it does in other browsers, too).

Comment: Dear Hars,  thanks for your reply i was allready tryed that but it wasn't work.